Tensor flow gets a different shape than expected when using train_on_batch()
I get an error when passing my data to train_on_batch() even though it has the correct shape when checking before.
def train(X_train,y_train, latent_dim, epochs=20, batch_size=128):
    #initializing the GAN
    generator=build_generator(latent_dim)
    discriminator=build_discriminator()
    gan=gan_net(generator,discriminator)
    
    batch_count = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size
    half_batch = batch_size // 2

    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
        print("###### @ Epoch",epoch)
        for _ in tqdm(range(batch_count)):
            x = randint(0, X_train.shape[0], half_batch)
            X, labels = X_train[x], y_train[x]
            y = np.ones((half_batch, 1))
            print(f"X: {X.shape}, labels: {labels.shape}, y: {y.shape}")
            # this prints out the correct shape: 
            # X: (64, 28, 28, 1), labels: (64, 6), y: (64, 1) 
            d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch([X, labels], y)
            # this line throws the error

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/.../Downloads/Project_newest_new.py", line 248, in <module> train(X_train,y_train,latent_dim,epochs=20,batch_size=128) File "/Users/.../Downloads/Project_newest_new.py", line 198, in train d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch([X, labels], y) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 551, in train_on_batch logs = self.train_function(data()) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 118, in one_step_on_iterator outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run( File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 106, in one_step_on_data return self.train_step(data) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 57, in train_step y_pred = self(x, training=True) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Reshape.call().

Cannot reshape a tensor with 301056 elements to shape [64,28,28,1] (50176 elements) for '{{node functional_3_1/reshape_2_1/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](functional_3_1/embedding_1_1/GatherV2, functional_3_1/reshape_2_1/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [64,6,784], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [64,28,28,1].

Arguments received by Reshape.call(): inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 6, 784), dtype=float32) 

I am confused because X, labels and y seem to have the correct shape when printing them manually X: (64, 28, 28, 1), labels: (64, 6), y: (64, 1) but train_on_batch() seems to get a different shape shape=(64, 6, 784).

The error you are facing suggests that there's a shape mismatch when trying to reshape tensors within the train_on_batch() method.The issue might be with the input shape of the discriminator model. First shapes of inputs expected by the discriminator model and the actual shapes of the inputs you're passing.for the image data and (6,) for the label data. You can verify this by examining the model architecture.Then, ensure that your build_discriminator() function is correctly defining the input layers to match these shapes.

It seems that the error is indicating that the discriminator is expecting inputs of shape (64, 6, 784) instead of (64, 28, 28, 1).
